# TilesViewResolver is not working while deploying as war

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, apache-tiles

I was created a sample project with Spring MVC and apache-tiles. My configurations are quite simple as below

Dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
....
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.test" />
<mvc:resources location="/" mapping="/**"></mvc:resources>
<bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
    <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>
<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tile-definition.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

tile-definition.xml

```
...
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="baseLayout" template="/WEB-INF/views/baseLayout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Spring MVC Tiles Example" />
        <put-attribute name="content" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="app_home" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

and only one controller as

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Model model) {
        return "app_home";
    }
}
```

Everythings work fine and nothing problems while running with Eclipse IDE. But when I generated **war** file and deployed it to Tomcat-8 server, `tilesViewResolver` was not intercepted. Why am I saying `tilesViewResolver` not work well , because I got 404 and the browser was trying to load **app_home.jsp**. This is logical view name for tiles and `tilesViewResolver` should intercept this before spring's `InternalViewResolver`.

Has somebody experience with it ? What am I missing ?

> Edit : Attached source code.

You can download full codes from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0mSWwt3M9rpS3pfV2FMWVNjLTg). I copy the war file from target folder and paste it to webapps directory of my Tomcat server.The problem is as I described at above.

Comment: Can you show us the war structure ?

Comment: @Reddy I attached source code.

Comment: Can you try moving the tiles definition xml under WEB-INF ?

Comment: Can you place your dispatcher-servlet.xml parallel to web.xml ? 

I also had faced 404 error issue when I placed my dispatcher-servlet.xml inside the classpath.

Comment: Open the war file and check your tiles/tile-definition.xml will be missing,it should be under `WEB-INF/` then only your war file will contain resources.

Comment: @Reddy Now I moved all tiles definition under `WEB-INF` folder but it is not ok yet. And I uploaded my updated codes in my project link. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Ankit I placed `dispatcher-servlet.xml` under `WEB-INF` folder  but it is not ok yet. And I uploaded my updated codes in my project link. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Sam At my updated codes my tiles definition.xml file is under `WEB-INF` and it was included after generating `war` file. But error is the same. What would I need to do ?

Comment: Can you remove internal view resolver and keep only tiles view resolver in dispatcher servlet..and check

Comment: what error do you get ? Can you share some stack trace ?

Comment: @Sam when I removed `InternalViewResolver` , dispatcherServlet can't redirect to my jsp.

Comment: @Reddy I didnot see any errors at console except `404`

Comment: Then your tiles resolver is not working at all...

Comment: `mvc:resources location="/" mapping="/**"></mvc:resources>` and mainly why you are mentioning all request as resources??

Comment: @Sam :) .. actually it is not need yet. I just add for all css,js,fonts for testing project.

Comment: Add for only resources otherwise it will intercept for all requests...

Comment: great that your application is working now. but in your dispatcher-servlet.xml you had defined two view resolver i.e. InternalResourceViewResolver and UrlBasedViewResolver. Also you didn't specified any bean with id viewResolver. So, how controller will be able to find resolver in your application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was a bug of apache-tiles version `3.0.3`. Now I upgraded to latest version *(currently **3.0.7**)* and everythings work fine. Thanks a lot to @Sam and @Reddy for helping me
 to put `tiles-definiton.xml` under `WEB-INF` directory. But actually it is not needed to have tiles definitions under `WEB-INF` folder.